# Substring in flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I want to use substring in flex side like eg:- m having sm no like 0001A,0287393A,22839A,etc
i need to use substring for numeric only and chop character value. Or else if you have sm other idea beside using substring can share much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question. You want to convert the numeric part of the string to a Number, and drop the characters. If so, you're in luck:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseInt()

`parseInt('0001a')` should return `Number(1)`.